# How do I server multiple domains from the same directory and codebase without my configuraton breaking when apache.conf is overwritten?

Tags: apache

I have 20 domains on a VPS running cPanel. One public_html is filled with code, the remaining 19 are symbolic links to that one. (For example, `assets` is a directory within `public_html` ... for the 19 others, there's a symbolic link to that directory in each each accounts `public_html` dir.)

It's all PHP / MySQL database driven, with content changing depending on the domain. It works like a charm, assuming cPanel has `suExec` enabled correctly, and assuming apache.conf does NOT have `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` enabled.

However, every few weeks, my `apache.conf` is mysteriously overwritten, re-enabling `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, and disabling all 19 linked sites for as long as it takes for me to notice. Here's the offending line in apache.conf:

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

The addition of `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` disables the sites in a strange way ... the html is generated correctly, but all css/js/image in the html fails to load. Clicking any link redirects to `/`. And I have no idea why. I do have a few things in my `.htaccess`, which work fine when `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` is not present:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # www.example.com -> example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Remove query strings from static resources
    RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*)_v(.*)\.js           /assets/js/$1.js [L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*)_v(.*)\.css         /assets/css/$1.css [L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/sites/(.*)/(.*)_v(.*)\.css  /assets/sites/$1/$2.css [L]

    # Block access to hidden files and directories  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    # SLIR ... reroute images to image processor
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.*$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

    # ignore rules if URL is a file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # ignore rules if URL is not php
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$

    # catch-all for routing
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

I also use most of the [5G Blacklist 2013](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/) for protection against exploits and other depravities. Again, all of this works great, except when `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` gets added back into apache.conf.

Since I've failed to find the cause of whatever cPanel/security update is overwriting apache.conf, I thought there might be a more correct way to accomplish my goal using group permissions.

I've created a 'www' group, added all accounts to the group, and `chmod -R`'d the code source to use that group. Everything is `644` or `755`. But doesn't seem to be enough. My unix isn't that strong. Do you need to restart something for group changes to take effect? Probably not. Anyways, I'm entering unknown territory.

Can anyone recommend the right way to configure a website for multiple sites using one codebase that doesn't rely on apache.conf?

Comment: I assume you are running an a Linux box.   Which distribution are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preserve Changes in Apache**

First, stop making changes to httpd.conf.

From `usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

> Direct modifications to the Apache configuration file may be lost upon
>   subsequent regeneration of the configuration file.

Further in that file it details how to provide overrides to the default configuration.

See the documentation at 
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache
under
Custom Directives to httpd.conf
To learn how to preserve configuration changes in httpd.conf on WHM/cPanel.

**Hosting Multiple Domains on Same DocRoot**

There are many methods to do this but one of the easiest is to use a  wildcard`ServerAlias *` in your httpd.conf.

You need to assure that primary account is on its own IP address for this to work.

Then check the cPanel docs on how to include directives inside of a `Virtualhost`

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/EasyApacheChangesWithinVirtualHost

If you set this up, then all you have to do is point a domains DNS to your site's main IP.

We use this setup with some customers that run Drupal or WordPress multi-site installations.

This will not give you email on this alternate domain but makes creating 100's of domains on the same code base as easy as updating DNS.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: I would have to test, but I think you may be able to do something similar with add-on/parked domains and just point them to the same document root.  I've just moved to using this wildcard method since it only requires a DNS setup to function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in your *.htaccess* file?

```
Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

---

I don't usually rely on symlinks to point multiple sites to the same code base.   Instead, I write a virtual host directive for each one and point them all to the same directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername site1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/allsites
    <Directory /var/www/allsites/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername site2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/allsites
    <Directory /var/www/allsites/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I have found on my Ubuntu systems that the *apache.conf* files get overwritten any time that Apache gets a major upgrade.   This usually only happens every six months when I upgrade to the latest Ubuntu release.   Apache security upgrades that happen periodically typically don't overwrite the configuration.   It could be that on your distribution, minor updates to Apache for security fixes are overwriting the configuration.